# How can I view the google drive image and video files from the react-native app?

Tags: image, react-native, google-drive-api, display, react-native-image

I want to display pictures in my react native app, but only know how to show the pictures from other url's but don't know how can I show the images from the drive in my app,

```
  <Image
      style={{width:50, height: 50}}
      source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react-native/img/tiny_logo.png'}}
   />
```

Above code displays the picture from the link but how can I display the pictures which are in google drive? tried giving sharable links as uri but no use.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -4):

1. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> while preview of image opened on Google Drive page.
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> and click on the image
3. Copy the URL in the inspection panel and put it as a source